# 3D roatations that commutes with 2D rotations

Tags: rotations

Given an element $g$ in matrix Lie group $SO(3)$ such that $g$ commutes with all elements in $SO(3)$ that represents rotation around $z-$axis. Are such element $g$ also forced to be a rotation around $z-$axis? Are there any other possibilities? Calculation argument should work, but I want a "clever" argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not difficult to see that $g$ must send the $z$-axis to the $z$-axis (consider that $g$ commutes with the $90^\circ$ rotation about the $z$ axis). So if $g$ is not a rotation about the $z$ axis, there is only one option: it flips the $z$ axis. However, such an operation again cannot commute with a $90^\circ$ rotation about the $z$ axis.